# AWS Athena partitioning - projected and otherwise - make queries run forever

Tags: amazon-web-services, partitioning, amazon-athena

I'm trying to introduce partitioning into an Athena table. By way of background, what I have is a kinesis data stream receiving events that are JSON data, a delivery stream that converts the JSON from text to orc via a glue table we'll call `glue-table` and writes them to `s3://bucket-name/path/year=!{timestamp:yyyy}/month=!{timestamp:MM}/day=!{timestamp:dd}/hour=!{timestamp:HH}/`.

With this setup, and no partitioning properties or fields set up in the glue table at all, there is automatically an external table in Athena named `glue-table` and with ~50 sample events run through kinesis, I have data in the appropriate path in S3 (`aws s3 ls s3://bucket-name/path/year=2022/month=08/day=31/hour=19` for example lists results). I can execute `SELECT * FROM glue-table` in Athena and get ~50 results in ~900ms.

If I execute `MSCK REPAIR TABLE glue_table` the result is `Partitions not in metastore: glue_table:year=2022/month=08/day=31/hour=19` which implies Athena is able to see that there ought to be partitions based on the templates it finds in the S3 path.

If I then do this to create a partitioned table using projections:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE paritioned_table (
    action string,
    createdat string
)
PARTITIONED BY (
    year integer,
    month integer,
    day integer,
    hour integer
)
STORED AS ORC
LOCATION 's3://bucket-name/path/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'classification'='orc', 
  'projection.year.type'='integer', 
  'projection.year.range'='2022,9999', 
  'projection.month.type'='integer', 
  'projection.month.range'='01,12',
  'projection.day.type'='integer', 
  'projection.day.range'='01,31', 
  'projection.hour.type'='integer', 
  'projection.hour.range'='00,24',
  'projection.enabled'='true', 
  'storage.location.template'='s3://bucket-name/path/year=${year}/month=${month}/day=${day}/hour=${hour}/');
```

and then execute `SELECT action, year FROM partitioned_table WHERE year=2022;` then Athena chews on the query for 3 minutes and then returns no results.

If I go modify the glue table so it has the same projection settings from TBLPROPERTIES in the above example set as Table Properties, and then execute `SELECT action, year FROM partitioned_table WHERE year=2022;` then Athena chews on the query for 3 minutes and then returns no results.

Interestingly, if I drop and recreate `partitioned_table` so that it's location is `s3://bucket-does-not-exist` then `SELECT action, year FROM partitioned_table WHERE year=2022;` also runs for 3+ minutes and then returns no results.

I'm not able to see what I'm doing wrong here after referring to multiple pages of AWS documentation and a few official AWS videos describing this process. What's wrong here?

Comment: How long will it take to run SELECT action, year FROM partitioned_table WHERE year=2022; with out partition projection? How many partitions in total, total data size, average file size?

Comment: In this test data set, there are at maximum 2 partitions, each with 20-30 "records." So not many. The query execution time seems constant, like it runs until it hits a timeout. the same query without partitions returns in under a second, so there's obviously something wrong with my partition setup, but I can't spot it.